# Can HTTP redirects be accomplished without an extra request/response?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http

I'm writing a Rails app where I have two methods, a "list" and a "query". Here's a simplified version:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    def query
        # query based on user-form text in params[:q]
        @list = Product.where(Product.arel_table[:description].matches("%#{params[:q]}%"))
        if @list.count == 1
          redirect_to :action => 'list', :id => @list[0].id
        end
    end

    def list
        @item= Product.find(params[:id])
    end
 end
```

By far the most common user pattern is to enter a search that yields a single product. When this happens, I want the url to redirect to the restful

```
http://myurl/list/:id
```

rather than

```
http://myurl/query?q=search-query.
```

But in the above code, I'm hitting the database twice to get the same record, and creating 2 http requests/responses for every query.  Not the end of the world, but I was wondering if there's a better way. (I already have the model object in-hand when I run the query)

Is there a clean way to render the list action's view from the query action and tell the browser the new URL without an extra request/response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not within the constraints of the http protocol.

Comment: Thanks, if there are no other takers I'll mark this as correct. What about the multiple db calls? (This might be a bigger win than saving the HTTP request.)

Comment: A typical way to deal with performance of the type you are concerned with would be to put an edge-level cache in front of your application.. (E.g. varnish or nginx would typically be the tool of choice for this)